# Параллельное выполнение функций на Python без threading

Tags: python, многопоточность, распараллеливание

Есть скрипт, представляющий собой бота для Telegram. Две функции, выполняющие разные задачи.

Первая отвечает на запросы пользователя (мгновенно), другая оповещает пользователей при появлении новости на сайте, периодически запрашивая содержимое страницы (тоже мгновенно), но в ней есть таймаут (не опрашивать же сайт каждую секунду, так?), поэтому их нельзя выполнять последовательно.

Кроме использования модуля **threading** и запуска одной из функций в режиме демона, другого решения не нашел. Не слишком ли это, использовать такой модуль только лишь для того, чтобы запустить простую функцию-демон?

```
import threading
from time import sleep

def function1():
    ...
    sleep(timeout)

def function2():
    ...

t = threading.Thread(target=function1)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

function2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще я лично не вижу особых проблем с `threading` в данном случае. Но если вы хотите все делать в одном потоке, то это весьма просто.

У вас в `function2()`, которая отвечает на запросы пользователя, скорее всего ведь цикл, так? Вот в конец его и вставьте проверку, не прошло ли заданное время с момента предыдущей обработки содержимого страницы с новостями, и если прошло, производите вызов функции `function1()`. Получится примерно такой код (с сохранением ваших имен функций):

```
import time

def function1():
    ...

def function2():
    ...

    latest_handling_ts = time.time()
    while True:
        # очередной ответ на запрос пользователя
        ...

        # проверка, не прошло ли время timeout с момента последнего
        # запроса и обработки содержимого страницы с новостями
        now = time.time()
        if now - latest_handling_ts > timeout:
            # заданное время прошло, запрашиваем содержимое страницы
            # и обрабатываем его
            function1()
            latest_handling_ts = now

function2()
```

Comment: Выглядит хорошо, но плохо. Представьте себе, что сайт, который отдает новости, немножко прилег. Ну совсем немножко. И страницы отдаются по несколько минут. Пользователи будут жаловаться на тупящего бота, который не отвечает "моментально".

Comment: В постановке задачи указано на мгновенную обработку. Но даже если это не так, все легко изменяется для этого случая с сохранением общей логики и структуры. Нужно использовать timeout для сокетов, и в случае невозможности получить содержимое не обнавлять время последней обработки.

Comment: А вообще, конечно, правильнее такую задачу решать с помощью мультиплексирования ввода-вывода (для python есть привязка к libev, например; но тут и обычным `select` вполне можно обойтись), или вообще заиспользовать `asyncio`, но это точно не будет проще использования модуля `threading`.

Comment: вот мультиплексирование это хорошо. А надеятся на моментальный отклик сайтов я бы не стал.

Comment: Спасибо,  @VadimShender, идея с проверкой таймаута мне сразу не пришла в голову (в силу того, что делаю первые шаги в программировании), а как раз она поможет мне.

Comment: @VadimShender, в функции, конечно, используется бесконечный цикл.
Просто я был озадачен, нормальное ли это явление, - использовать `threading` для "демонизации".

Comment: @MaksimMelnikov, использование `threading` -- вполне нормальная практика. Я даже скорее всего ее бы и порекомендовал вам оставить, как самое простое из возможных решений, так как для того, чтобы надежно и хорошо сделать в одном потоке, подобно предложенной мною схеме, придется учесть ряд ньюансов, как было озвучено выше в комментариях.